# Get days between a date and now using the time() function

Tags: c

I want to get a number of days from a certain date to current date.
Here is my current code that gets the days from 1/1/1970.

```
int days_since_my_birth(int day, int month, int year) {

    time_t sec;
    sec = time(NULL);

    printf("Number of days since birth is %ld \n", sec / 86400);

    return d;
}
```

Can I use the `time()` function to get the number of seconds from a date I entered?

Comment: 1) Convert birthday to `time_t` with `mktime()`.  (might have trouble if born before Jan 1, 1970)  2) Get current time with `time()`  3) Get difference in seconds with `difftime()` then divide by (60*60*24).

Comment: `man mktime`, `man difftime`. *Update*: Ok, @chux wins...

Comment: Why `"Number of hours since birth"` with the goal of "get the amount of days"?

Comment: @chux sorry that should of been days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how i done it in the end. it doesnt work if the birthday entered is before 1970. thanks for all the help.

i only just started learning c so there is probably more efficient ways to do it.

```
int days_since_my_birth(int day, int month, int year) {

    //create a time struct and initailize it with the function parameters   
    struct tm time_info = { 0 };
    time_info.tm_year = year - 1900;
    time_info.tm_mon = month -1;
    time_info.tm_mday = day;

    //get the number of seconds from 1970
    int n = time(NULL);

    // convert the birthdate to seconds
    double birthday = mktime(&time_info);
    // convert the birthdate to days
    birthday = (birthday / 86400);
    //get the no of days alive by subtracting birthdate days
    int result = (n / 86400) - birthday;

    return result;

}
```

Comment: This solution is prone to off-by-1 errors as 1) `mktime()` input is timezone sensitive, but the result discards time-zone data and 2) `double` to `int` truncation toward 0.  This affects the `(n / 86400) - birthday` calculation.  Try this function with today's date, like `printf("%d\n", days_since_my_birth(2, 10, 2016));
  printf("%d\n", days_since_my_birth(3, 10, 2016));
  printf("%d\n", days_since_my_birth(4, 10, 2016));` and see if you get 2 or 3 difference results.  Depending on _your_ timezone, try this before and after midnight (midnight UTC time) to see the other problem.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the julian day integer of the earlier date from the julian integer of the later date.  The following tells you exactly how to do that.

http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~cs1063/projects/Spring2011/Project1/jdn-explanation.html

Otherwise, http://pdc.ro.nu/jd-code.html already has a C version

```
long gregorian_calendar_to_jd(int y, int m, int d)
{
    y+=8000;
    if(m<3) { y--; m+=12; }
    return (y*365) +(y/4) -(y/100) +(y/400) -1200820
          +(m*153+3)/5-92
          +d-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Get days between a date and now using the time() function

```
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
int days_since_my_birth(int day, int month, int year, double *days) {

  struct tm birthdate = { 0 };  // set all fields to 0
  birthdate.tm_year = year - 1900;
  birthdate.tm_mon = month - 1;  // Months since January
  birthdate.tm_mday = day;
  birthdate.tm_isdst = -1;  // Let system determine if DST was in effect

  // Form timestamp for the birthdate.
  time_t birth_time = mktime(&birthdate);
  if (birth_time == -1) return FAIL;

  time_t now;
  if (time(&now) == -1) return FAIL;

  // Calculate difference in seconds and convert to days.
  // Round as desired  (rint(), floor(), etc.)
  *days = floor(difftime(now, birth_time)/86400);
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

> Can I use the time() function to get the number of seconds from a date I entered?

Maybe,  `time(NULL)` is not specified by C to return seconds nor since a certain epoch like Jan 1, 1970 - although that is commonly implemented that way.

`difftime()` returns the difference in seconds.

Comment: im getting exception when trying to run your code i managed to figure out how to do it myself i have add my solution to the thread. may i ask why you have *days as a function parameter and not declared as a local variable?

Comment: @Swannie `*days` is used to return the days alive value.  The return value form this function indicates success or failure.  Concerning "getting exception ", how are you calling the function?  Like `double d; if( days_since_my_birth(3, 10, 2016, &d) == SUCCESS) printf("%f\n", d);`?